# EGit refactor rename project NOT renames git working tree folder

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

If I do refactor rename (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>) a project (which updates the references along with the resource name change) in Eclipse which was shared in git repository, then the **.project** file will be changed and shown in **Git Staging** view.

But project folder was not renamed in the git working directory, so the project name in Package/Navigator view shown is different than in the git working directory.

Is it a bug in EGit? Or are there any ways to do automatically change the folder name in git working directory, so that I can commit these changes.

Note that renaming other folders/files is working fine.

Answer (score 7):

Just use **Refactor -> Move** after right click on the project. You can also use (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>). Seems to manage git all right.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is unrelated to Git or EGit. In Eclipse, a workspace project is not represented through the file system folder it is located in. It is the `.project` file that describes the project.

While usually a project is located in a folder of the same name this isn't required. For example a project named `bar` could be located in folder `foo`

```
/path/to/foo/.project
```

Contents of `.project`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projectDescription>
  <name>bar</name>
  ...
</projectDescription>
```

The *Rename Project* command does not touch the folder in which the project is located. The command only changes the name of the project as it appears in the `.project` file.

Consequentially, EGit will show the `.project` file as changed but nothing else. As [borjab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16206/borjab) suggests, youd can use the *Move* (<kbd>Alt+Shift V</kbd>) command to change the location of a project.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem here is that the project root folder is not part of the git repository. So you cannot change the name of the project directory from your local clone. If you are using git hub you can change the name of the repository as shown [here](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/).

Steps for changing the project name (I hope this works)

1. Refactor your project from eclipse
2. Push all the changed files to remote git hub (this will contain the .project file)
3. [Rename](https://help.github.com/articles/renaming-a-repository/) the repo in the github .

I hope this helps.

Comment: Its not about renaming the repository and also I am interested ONLY in git not in github.

Comment: Same problem here and it is not he case. I have a Modules GIt repository with several projects. If I rename project foo to on modules/foo directory to bar it does not move to modules/bar path.